# Sending files from AWS IoT to S3 but bucket is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-iot

I am sending a file from an IoT device and trying to store into S3. I have created a rule and created a role with policy s3:PutObject for the rule. On publishing the file I am checking the bucket and it remains empty.

Question 1: I am not authorized to create policy yet I could create this one while creating the rule wherein I was given an option of choosing a role or create one on the spot. I created one on that spot. Since I am not authorized to create one, is this why my policy is not being accepted and hence the bucket is not being populated by the file I am expecting?

Question 2: While creating the rule, what is the key? In [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/aws-iot-rule-actions.html#s3-rule), it says it is the path to the file where data is written. Whereas in [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingObjects.html), it says it's version Id. Current, I have kept it as null since I haven't enabled versioning. I am pretty confused on what is the key and is that the reason why in my case the bucket is not being populated.

Comment: Have you figured out the answer to question 2? I also am confused about that as there seems to be conflicting information on the AWS website.

Comment: I think you are talking about the key. The key is the path to the file where data is written and not the version Id.

Comment: Also having same issue did you resolved? what could be the solution?

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 0):

You must store files in a DynamoDB as JSON, then create a Data Pipeline to save them in S3. Be sure to grant the proper permissions to execute this task. Check my tutorial on this in my [GitHub.](https://github.com/RubensZimbres/Repo-2018/tree/master/CPU%20Temperature%20-%20IoT%20Project)

Also, be sure the shadow is being updated and messages are being published in your IoT Core monitoring tool. You can also create a Cloudwatch to count the number of items in your DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use DynamoDB in the middle of this. You can move directly from IoT Core to S3. The key is the file name.